# Why is my Android app gradle build failing?

Tags: android, gradle, plugins, build

Android Studio version 3.1 canary 8

app level **gradle.build**

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
  }
}

repositories {
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Sun Feb 11 01:51:40 EAT 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists 
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

**Error stack trace:**
http://dpaste.com/23744GK

Comment: see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710214/how-to-solve-this-in-android-studio-3-0/48710607#48710607

Comment: Try To  rebuild project with stable internet connection

Answer (score 0):

use lower version of this

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```